# Proving $n\cdot\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2}\bigg) \leqslant (n\cdot|x_{n}|)^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

May this be proved by induction?

> Let $x \in \mathcal{R}^{n}$, where $|x_{n}| \geqslant |x_{i}|$, $i \neq n$. In other words, $|x_{n}|$ is the maximal element of $x$. Then, 
>   $$ 
>     n\cdot\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2}\bigg) \leqslant (n\cdot|x_{n}|)^{2}.
> $$

I believe this is an always true inequality. However, since the statement is regarding the maximal element, will induction fail since $|x_{n+1}|$ is not this maximal element?

If I am off track, how may I prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: If $|x_i|\le |x_n|$, then $|x_i|^2\le |x_n|^2$. If you add the $|x_i|^2$s, what is an obvious upper bound for the sum?

Comment: Is this correct? If you add the $|x_{i}|^{2}$s, then you have $n(|x_{1}|^{2} + \cdots + |x_{n}|^{2})$, but each $|x_{i}|^{2} \leq |x_{n}|^{2}$. Then, it implies that $n(|x_{1}|^{2} + \cdots + |x_{n}|^{2}) \leq n(|x_{n}|^{2} + \cdots + |x_{n}|^{2}) = n^{2}|x_{n}|^{2} = (n|x_{n}|)^{2}$?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly right :)

Comment: Induction will not fail because "$|x_{n+1}|$ is not the maximal element."  It is the maximal element.  In fact, inductively, $|x_{n+1}|>x_i$ indeed for all $i\le n$.